# access previous input param in CompletableFuture chains

Tags: java, lambda, completable-future

I have a chained CompletableFuture call,

```
void handle(ParamA paramA) { 
  CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> methodA(paramA))
            .thenApply(resultA -> methodB(paramA, resultA))
            .thenApply(resultB -> methodC(resultA, resultB)); 
}
```

the problem is that, for the methodC, it requires params produced in the previous call, but the parameter is out of scope, how could I access the resultA?

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like so,

```
CompletableFuture cfA = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> methodA(paramA));
CompletableFuture cfB = cfA.thenApply(resultA -> methodB(paramA, resultA));
cfA.thenCombine(cfB, (resultA, resultB) -> methodC(resultA, resultB));
```